# Social sharing with hyperlink text in Sencha application using Cordova social sharing plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, extjs, whatsapp, socialshare

I have added plugin in my sencha application

```
cordova plugin add nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing
```

for Email sharing image and text

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.ShareViaEmail('<a href="www.hello.com">Message via WhatsApp</a>', 'www/image/demo.png', 'https://hello.com', function() {console.log('share ok')}, function(errormsg){alert(errormsg)})
```

for whatsapp sharing image and text

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsApp('<a href="www.hello.com">Message via WhatsApp</a>', 'www/image/demo.png', 'https://hello.com', function() {console.log('share ok')}, function(errormsg){alert(errormsg)})
```

The method is working for email and whatsapp both but message is sharing in email fine 
like   if we click on the message "Message via WhatsApp" It will redirect to hello.com 
but in whatsapp message is sharing with href tag

please suggest me what i need to do for share hyperlink message on whatsapp

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not able to understand what you try to say.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer  I just want to share text on whatsapp. if we click on text it will be open and website witch is define in href tag lie this <a href="www.hello.com">Message via WhatsApp</a> here is one condition that href tag will be hide